# What is the difference between `GetAsync` and `ExecuteGetAsync` in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

What is the difference between the methods `RestClient.GetAsync` and `RestClient.ExecuteGetAsync`? When should I use one or the other?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GetAsync will throw an exception if the server returns an error because it is not part of RestClient interface and return `Task<int>` i.e. there is no way to set and response status code.

while

ExecuteGetAsync will not throw an exception if the server return an error because it's return type is RestResponse and it has ResponseStatus property to set an error.

For more information:
https://restsharp.dev/error-handling.html